# How to fix "TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers'" when using gpt-index/llama-index?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api

I am trying to use gpt-index/llama-index to feed ChatGPT with custom data to build a custom chatbot. When I try to import either gpt-index or llama-index to Jupyter, I get the following error.

[image: Error Message]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but the problem persists.

I am using Python 3.9.16 on Jupyter Notebook 6.4.8